# unable to bind ModelMap through ajax call in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

MY JSP PAGE:

```
<form action="manageparentexamforchildren.htm" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" >
              <div class="form-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="control-label col-md-1"><spring:message code="label.parent.children"/></label>
                              <div class="col-md-3">
                                <select name="parent.children" class="form-control" id="children" required="true" >
                                    <option value="">-<spring:message code="label.select"/>-</option>
                                    <c:forEach items="${studentsOfThisParent}" var="student">
                                       <option value="${student.id}">${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}</option>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </select>
                              </div>
                </div>

                </div>
              <div class="form-actions fluid">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn blue"><i class="icon-ok"></i><spring:message code='button.search'/></button>
                      <button type="button" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);" class="btn red default"><spring:message code='button.cancel'/></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>


            <c:forEach items="${modelList}" var="examination">
    <tr>
      <td><b><spring:message code="label.examination.schoolexam"/></b>:<c:out value="${examination.schoolExam.name}" /></td>
    </tr>

    <table border="1" width="1000" height="200" class="table table-bordered table-hover"> 
   <thead> <tr><th class="active"><spring:message code="label.examination.subjects"/></th><th class="active"><spring:message code="label.exam.Date"/></th><th class="active"><spring:message code="label.exam.maxmarks"/></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${examination.examinationSubjects}" var="examinationSubject" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
    <td class="success"><c:out value="${examinationSubject.subjects.name}" /></td>
    <td class="success" ><c:out value="${examinationSubject.date}" /></td>
    <td class="success"><c:out value="${examinationSubject.maxMarks}" /></td>

    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
    </table>

  </c:forEach>
```

MY CONTROLLER:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/manageparentexam.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String manageparentexam(ModelMap modelMap,HttpServletRequest request )
    {

        Parent parent = parentService.getParentById(getLoggedInUser().getId());
        List <Student> studentsOfThisParent=parentService.getStudentsOfThisParent(getLoggedInUser().getId());
        Student student=null;

            student=parent.getStudentAdmission().get(0).getStudent();
            modelMap.addAttribute("modelList",student.getStudentAdmission().getClasses().getExamination());


        setupCreate(modelMap, request);
        return "tileDefinition.manageparentexam-"+getNameSpace();
    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/manageparentexamforchildren.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public void manageparentexamforchildren(ModelMap modelMap,HttpServletRequest request )
        {
            Long studentId=Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("parent.children"));
            modelMap.addAttribute("modelList",studentService.getById(studentId).getStudentAdmission().getClasses().getExamination());
            setupCreate(modelMap, request);
         }
```

here my requirement is,when ever,i select  a value in select box,then the table should get updated through ajax,here i am unable to bind the model list through ajax call . . .

Comment: What do you mean by: "bind the model list through ajax call" and what do you mean by "I am unable" -- what happend instead (what do you expect to be happend)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is separate the table in another jsp.  yourTable.jsp like this

```
        <table border="1" width="1000" height="200" class="table table-bordered table-hover"> 
             <thead> <tr><th class="active"><spring:message code="label.examination.subjects"/></th><th class="active"><spring:message code="label.exam.Date"/></th><th class="active"><spring:message code="label.exam.maxmarks"/></th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
     <c:forEach items="${examination.examinationSubjects}" var="examinationSubject" varStatus="status">
<tr>
<td class="success"><c:out value="${examinationSubject.subjects.name}" /></td>
<td class="success" ><c:out value="${examinationSubject.date}" /></td>
<td class="success"><c:out value="${examinationSubject.maxMarks}" /></td>

</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Then you include this jsp in your main mapge inside a div

```
    <div id="yourTable"> 
       <c:jsp include="yourTable.jsp/>
   </div>
```

Then in your select you have to add a listener and when something has change you need to make a JQuery load lo reload the table rendering the table from the controller again with all the changes that you want

```
              $('#yourTable').load("url of your controller where you will render yourTable.jsp");
```

And in the controller you will render yourTable.jsp and you will add in the ModelAndView object the examinationSubject